# What is the maximum stack size for potions in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

Question is pretty self-explanatory. How many potions of the same type can I have in one stack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Potions stack to 100.](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/minor-health-potion)

It's quite nice, actually.

Comment: That's lovely :)