# What are the maximum stack values of the various consumables and commodities?

Tags: diablo-iii

**I'd like to know what the maximum stack sizes of the different consumable items and crafting materials in the game are.** I know from experience and [from this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66655/what-is-the-maximum-stack-size-for-potions-in-diablo-3) that potions will stack up to 100, as will the various item salvaging materials. But what about gems, pages of Blacksmithing/Jewelcrafting, et al? Are these all 100 as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gems stack to 30, as for the pages I have stacks of 100 each but I haven't tried having above that, but I find it unlikely they would stack above 100

Edit: Artisan pages stack to 1000

Comment: Pages do go above 100.

Comment: There you go, apparently they do. Odd that other crafting resources don't then...

Comment: As of patch 1.04, gems now stack up to 100.

Comment: As of the date of this comment, I have 181 of a single gem. I have no idea what the max size is...maybe 200 like WoW is nowadays? I actually noticed this, not while playing, but after coding ItemStacks for my own game project. It's interesting, though!